# Android get image from gallery and send to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

MainActivity:

```
 Intent get_image_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 get_image_intent.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(get_image_intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();

 Log.i(TAG, "imageUri " + imageUri);


        Intent image_gallery = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        image_gallery.putExtra("path", imageUri);
        startActivity(image_gallery);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
    String imageUri = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");


    try {


        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imageUri));
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

My app crashes with error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aptean.com.routesetter/aptean.com.routesetter.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
```

When I select image in MainActivity I get:

> content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1389928851

But when I send it to SecondActivity I get null.

Comment: Did you try to parse it? Something like, `String.valueOf(uri)` ?

Comment: Before you send it (i.e. in `MainActivity`) .. is it null?

Comment: Its not null in MainActivity. @Ticherhaz - where would I need to do that?

Comment: `putExtra("path, imageUri);` That should be `putExtra("path",  imageUri.toString());`

Comment: Problem #1: as blackapps notes, you are putting a `Uri` into the extra, and you are trying to get a `String` out. A `Uri` is not a `String`. You need to be consistent in the types that you use. Problem #2: Passing the `Uri` via an extra will not work AFAIK. Pass it in the "data" facet of the `Intent`, and include `FLAS_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html for more.